# Reading NFC card (PN532) with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

I am trying to detect a RFID card using the NFC-PN532 module and Adafruit_PN532 library.

Initialization code:-

```
#include <Adafruit_PN532.h>
#include <Wire.h> 

#define SCK  (13)
#define MISO (12)
#define MOSI (11)
#define SS   (10)
Adafruit_PN532 nfc(SCK, MISO, MOSI, SS);

void setup()
{  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Initializing please wait.......");
  delay(3000);
  nfc.begin();

  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata) 
  {
    Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
    while (1); // halt
  }

  Serial.print("Device Found PN5 Chip"); 
  Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX); 
  Serial.print("Firmware version > "); 
  Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC); 
  Serial.println((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);
  nfc.SAMConfig(); //Set to read RFID tags
  Serial.println("Waiting for RFID Card ...");
}
```

Main loop:-

```
void loop() 
{
  uint8_t success = 0;
  uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
  uint8_t uidLength;
  success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, uid, &uidLength);
  if (success) 
  {
      Serial.println("Card Detected!");
  }
  else
  {
      Serial.println("Card Not Detected or Removed!");
  }
}
```

Whenever i place a valid card on the PN532, *Card Detected!* is printed on the serial monitor.

However, when i remove the card, *Card Not Detected or Removed!* does not get printed.

How can i make the program  to loop in such a way that it can detect when the card is present/removed?

Comment: once you fix this (not sure why it is behaving this way)  you wont detect when a card is removed ... you'll detect when a card is not present ... there's a difference :p

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, you are right. But then how do i modify the code to detect "card inserted"and "card removed"?

Comment: you'd achieve that with code that only prints card removed if this is the first `loop` after card was present, ... try adding `nfc.setPassiveActivationRetries(0x10);` to your setup just before `nfc.SAMConfig();` - this should stop the code waiting for a card :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behaviour of `readPassiveTargetID` is to wait "forever" for a card - which is why your code only sees when there is a card present

So, in setup() add `nfc.setPassiveActivationRetries(0x10);` as follows - comments came from my own code, but I'm sure they were originally in some example or other :p

```
// Set the max number of retry attempts to read from a card
// This prevents us from waiting forever for a card, which is
// the default behaviour of the PN532.
nfc.setPassiveActivationRetries(0x10);

// configure board to read RFID tags
nfc.SAMConfig();
```

As for "detecting" removal

```
void loop() 
{
  static bool wasSuccess = false;
  uint8_t success = 0;
  uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
  uint8_t uidLength;
  success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, uid, &uidLength);
  if (success) 
  {
      wasSuccess = true;
      Serial.println("Card Detected!");
  }
  else if (wasSuccess)
  {
      wasSuccess = false;
      Serial.println("Card Removed!");
  }
  else
  {
      // you may want to remove this, it will flood the output :p
      Serial.println("Card Not Detected!");
  }
}
```

Comment: @Patrick - including the detection of remove? I ask, because I've been meaning to write some code for my PN532 :p